# Replace while loop in Tkinter without using a function

Tags: python, while-loop, tkinter

There are hundreds of questions involving a `while True:` loop in Tkinter (which of course crashes it, because it never executes the `mainloop()` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972115/while-loop-in-tkinter-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25731997/python-while-loop-causes-entire-program-to-crash-in-tkinter) for two of hundreds of examples)). The obvious (and so far only) answers require a function of some sorts.

My question is: is there any way to have something similar to a `while True:` loop in Tkinter that doesn't crash, *without* using a function? I didn't find any questions like this.

Comment: Why without using a function?

Comment: Because using a function makes the code annoying and fiddly to work with, and I'm really not bothered to deal with it (programmers program because they're lazy, right? No offense). If there's no answer, it's back to the fiddling.

Comment: You'll find it less fiddly the more you practice it. Anyway, it's certain to be less fiddly than alternative hacks (if they exist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with python and tkinter, but this should work:

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading

root = tk.Tk()
thread = threading.Thread(target=root.mainloop)
thread.start()

while True:
    print("Hello, World!");
    # TODO - add more stuff to this while loop
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `thread.start()` is a function. It's just defined in a different file.

Comment: Sorry, I should have rephrased that question - it just means *without* using a function *inside* of the file itself. EDIT: It works! Thanks!

Comment: When expanded to a real program, this will likely crash. Tkinter isn't thread safe; you should normally only ever call `mainloop` from the same thread that created the widgets.